# Android Graphics Making Line/Bar Graphs

Tags: android, layout, graphics, graph

I need to create a graph for a page of an android app i am creating. I have looked everywhere on line, but i can't find a good tutorial for graphics and graphing? And i also don't want to use somebody else's code.

What methods am i supposed to use inorder to create a proper layout for lets say a line graph?

Can anybody recommend a tutorial for making a graph that is actually usefull?

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to use an existing graphing library to produce line/bar graphs?

Comment: I don't want to get into the whole copyright mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library [chartdroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/) without having to worry about any copyright mess.

Otherwise [go here](http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing) for a tutorial that might help you write your own.

Comment: For the chartdroid library how do i use it within my application? I am new to Android so i don't really know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented graphs a while back using the jQuery based JavaScript library flot to draw graphs on android in a webview. Graphs can be drawn using HTML and JavaScript files stored locally, or from the internet. You'll find some useful information to get you started [here](http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing) but i dont know of any tutorials, i think writing your own code from scratch to display graphs would be alot of work, i think you should consider using existing libraries!